# How to use Include paths for IntelliSense in VS code with C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, include-path

Visual Studio Code has the possibility to use an external compiler to build and debug the code. It also has an IntelliSence module to highlight the code syntaxis and has a variable includePath to let the IntelliSence know where to find header files. But is there any possibility to supply the compiler with these include paths? Or I must support also a make file with the same set of directories?

Answer (score 0):

If you click a highlighted include that it can't find right away, a lightbulb icon should show up. Click it and Edit the IncludePath setting. This will create a .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json in your project folder.

Naturally, you can create the file yourself as well. Here's a quick one from my laptop:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Maybe I've explained badly. Intellisense can find everything. The question is how to pass this directory list to the compiler.

Comment: As far as I've understood from other resources no way to do it. And no way to use the path list from some makefile for the IntelliSence. I have to support both lists.

Comment: Yes, you've worded poorly. It sounded like Intellisense was the problem and not actual compilation. Create a build task and supply the directories there. Or go up a level and use cmake, to which you would supply the directories, and cmake will generate your makefiles for you.